# Gmail for android adds a gap in my email layout

Tags: android, html, gmail, html-email

Gmail in android devices adds a gap to an image in my layout. I know it's a common problem, I've read some solutions and tryed them, but they would'nt work.

I've tried with:

- Adding `display: block` to my images (inline styles)
- Wrapping the images with p `style="margin: 0;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;"`
- Adding `style="line-height: 0"` to my td and img
- Setting `margin:-2px` or `margin:0` to my td and img

None of them work, if someone can tell me why, I'll be more than grateful

Answer (score 0):

For images in it's own table try line-height: 50%;
 so your code should look like this 
 I found an css guide on line that gives the complete breakdown of the css support for the most popular email clients. 
[css guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)